# Incorrect order of stack, identity geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used dplyr to filter a dataset, which resulted in the tibble below.  I want to create a stacked bar chart of the types of features and their capability levels.  I would like the bar chart to be ordered from largest frequency to smallest.

Using the code below, the plot that is output has the first two values reversed.  Is this because "Position" only has two capability levels, whereas the rest have 3? Even then the highest frequency overall is 96 and belongs to a "Distance" level.

I would ideally like to do the least amount of "brute forcing" to make the code work as the actual data I am working with have over 10 types of features, some with only one capability level.

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   Type.of.Feature [?]
   Type.of.Feature Capability.Category  Freq
   <fct>           <chr>               <int>
 1 Diameter        <1                     75
 2 Diameter        >1.33                   5
 3 Diameter        1-1.33                 13
 4 Distance        <1                     96
 5 Distance        >1.33                   5
 6 Distance        1-1.33                  6
 7 Position        <1                     90
 8 Position        >1.33                   4
 9 Radius          <1                      7
10 Radius          >1.33                   1
11 Radius          1-1.33                  2


ggplot(freq, aes(x=reorder(Type.of.Feature, -Freq), y=Freq, fill=Capability.Category)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```

[image]

Comment: See if this is it: `reorder(Type.of.Feature, -Freq, FUN = sum)`. The default is `FUN = mean`.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much, @RuiBarradas!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below procedure to order your bars

```
#Import Data
file1<- readxl::read_excel(file.choose())

#Import Required Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#Split Dataframe into list based on the Type.of.Feature factor
factor_list <-split.data.frame(file1, f= file1$Type.of.Feature)


#Create new column with frequency sum for each of the level of factor above
for( lnam in names(factor_list)){
  factor_list[[lnam]]["group_sum"]<- sum(factor_list[[lnam]]["Freq"])
}

#Get back the data into dataframe
file1<- rbind_list(factor_list)

#Use newly created group frequency to order your bars
ggplot(file1, aes(x=reorder(Type.of.Feature, -group_sum), y=Freq, fill=Capability.Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```